# Enforce Encryption on SNS creation by SCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-sns, aws-organizations

I would like to create an SCP to enforce encryption on SNS creation. I am creating the below policy but it has not worked.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "sns:CreateTopic"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "attributes:KmsMasterKeyId": "alias/aws/sns"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "it has not worked" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? how do you test and how can anyone reproduce the issue?

Comment: When I try to create SNS with either encryption enable or disable in member account I get the same below error.

Comment: Couldn't create topic.
Error code: AuthorizationError - Error message: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:root is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:XXXXXXX:SNSTest with an explicit deny in a service control policy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where did you find `attributes:KmsMasterKeyId` condition key, but based on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsns.html), `sns:CreateTopic` does not support such a condition.

Comment: I mistakenly put "attributes:KmsMasterKeyId" in here but I am trying without attribute in front "KmsMasterKeyId": "alias/aws/sns" but got the same error.

Comment: @ShaifulAlam Please check docts. KmsMasterKeyId is not supported.